# Shifting modulus to another side of equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I was having some problem when trying to calculate for modular.

So I got 9 = (10+b) mod 23. What should I do to get the b?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$9=10+b\mod23\\-1=b\mod 23\\b=22+23k\\k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Hello do you mind to explain a little bit more on the third step? I got confused when shifting over the modular

Comment: @DeniseTan The solution is actually $b=-1\mod 23$, and the solutions are all numbers that are 22 more then a number that is divisible by 23.